# Plane rotation lesson

Tags: geometry, triangles, rotations

Given a point $A$ and two parallel lines $(D)$ and $(D')$ not passing through $A$. Construct a point $B$ on $(D)$ and a point $C$ on $(D')$ such that $\Delta ABC$ is direct equilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_A^{60^{\circ}}$ be a rotation by $60^{\circ}$ around the point $A$.

Let $R_A^{60^{\circ}}((D'))\cap (D)=\{B\}$ and $R_A^{-60^{\circ}}(B)=\{C\}$.

Thus, $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Let $R_A^{-60^{\circ}}$ be a rotation by $-60^{\circ}$ around the point $A$.

Let $R_A^{-60^{\circ}}((D'))\cap (D)=\{B\}$ and $R_A^{60^{\circ}}(B)=\{C\}$.

Thus, $\Delta ABC$ is a direct equilateral triangle.

Comment: @Abed Shaar No! I meant to the exactly, which I wrote.

Comment: We must agree on something before discussing for better understanding and that is when a line is rotated by 60°, we write $((D), (D'))$=60° and not $((D'), (D))$=60°. Right?

Comment: http://imgur.com/6w4CfjW

Comment: If you took a look at the image linked above. The triangle on the left is the one made by your method and as you can see it resulted in an indirect equilateral triangle ABC. Meanwhile, the one on the right is direct and was made by the way I suggested you to edit.

Comment: @Abed Shaar I made $R_{A}^{60^{\circ}}((D'))$. See please better my solution. The rotation by $60^{\circ}$ is counter clock wise.

Comment: I wrote in the picture $R ((D))$ by mistake. I forgot the prime. But I actually drew $R ((D'))$

Comment: Only the label was wrong. My bad

Comment: But if there is still a mistake in my drawing. Please let me know. I followed your steps and repeated them.

Comment: @Abed Shaar The left triangle it's the triangle, which I meant. Maybe you mean that there is another triangle. If so then your are right!

Comment: The left triangle has an indirect sense. Take a look. It is oriented clockwise (indirect) and the question said that ABC must be **direct**. That's  what I meant :)

Comment: @Abed Shaar I don't understand what is it "direct equilateral triangle". I thought that it's just equilateral triangle. If you know what is it and you think that I helped you then it's all correct. You can fix my post.

Comment: http://imgur.com/oVFiYDw . A direct triangle is a triangle oriented in the direct sense. Just follow the letters of the triangle. Check the image. And thanks alot

Comment: @Abed Shaar You are welcome!

Comment: @AbedShaar Perhaps you’re translating into English, but “direct” and “indirect” are not standard terms for orientation. I take it that by “direct” you mean “counterclockwise” or “positive,” which are the more usual terms.

Comment: @amd If that so, I apologise. Our curriculum is based on French system and our books are translated.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg . For sure. I'm still a beginner with this stuff. Also my bad.

Comment: @Abed Shaar All correct. Thank you!